# NFA's regular expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

Which of the following is not a correct regular expression for this λ-NFA?  ( it uses ε instead of λ.)

Select one:

a. (λ + a + ab)(a + b)

b. a  + (ab + a)(a + b)

c. a + aa + ab + aba + abb

d. a + a(a + b) + ab(a +b)

I believe I know how a and c are, but I don't see how either b or d are..meaning one of them must be right but I can't see it because the NFA is directional and there are not any states that point to itself...

Comment: The language recognized by the NFA has exactly five words in it; write them out, then expand each of the regular expressions to find the one that doesn’t generate the right five words. And you need to check your work so far, because (a) and (c) don’t give the same language.

Comment: Ok. The only way I see 5 words is if the "a,b"from 4 to 5 is a or b, and not ab. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it’s $a$ or $b$; that’s standard notation.

Comment: oh I see. that helps out a lot. thank you

Comment: You’re welcome.